# Scroll to specific line number with syntaxHighlighter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, syntaxhighlighter

[i have a div panel, when i click on a button it shows up, with scroller on position 0 on lines number "gutter"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRTOZ.png)

[i have a highlight line on line 200 and 201 as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVp7p.png)

```
<pre class="brush: php;highlight:[24,25,28,29,30,200,201]; toolbar: false;">

               <?php

             $html = file_get_contents("index.php");
             echo htmlspecialchars($html);
              ?>

               </pre>
```

**Edit:the problem is that i can't grab the number line because it's belong to syntax highlighter plugin 
and the source code is frome another file ( file_get_contents...)**

i want to scroll automatically to line number 201 when i click on button to show my panel.... it's that possible ? I looked everywhere for a solution in vain, could you please help me ?

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you highlight the line I assume you can get the line element in your code. Then you can scroll window to that element:

```
var line = $(/*your highlighted line*/);
var offset = line.offset();
window.scrollTo(offset.left, offset.top);
```

Comment: @BendimeradAdelReda, did my answer help or are you still struggling with it?